# One file shared among multiple projects with source control

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

How do you deal with a scenario where multiple projects must share a file(s).

Using visual sourcesafe, a single file can be shared by multiple projects and when it is checked out in one, it is set as checked out in all of them. Editing the file in one project will edit the file in all projects, but deleting the file from one project won't delete it from the others.

Is it possible to work like this using git, svn or team foundation?

General thoughts on the scenario described and whether this should be the work flow are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Pinning and shared source is considered a bad practice and can lead to all sorts of issues.

You might be better with a Nuget solution! Nuget can add and update files instead of adding reference DLL's. You can have a separate solution that has your shared files that outputs a Nuget package. Each of your other solutions can take a dependency on this package.

If you just want to share a file between projects in the same solution you can simply have a single copy in a shared folder under the solution and "link" to that from each of your projects.

When you "add an existing file" to your project you should see a drop down list as part of the add button that has "link" as an option. One file, many projects. Deleting the link does not delete the file.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into Nuget. Why are shared resources considered a bad practice?

Comment: Code sharing is a bad practice as it introduces bugs and reduces overall quality. If a change is made to your shared code that is good for ProductA but breaks ProductB how can you ship? You cant, and now you have technical debt. There is always a better way to solve the problem. Linked Files, Nuget Packaging, or even (shudder) branching.